# How does kpm manage content folders in a NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, nuget, asp.net-core

I'm running Visual Studio 15 Preview, and started a new project: ASP.NET Web Application > ASP.NET 5 Empty. I then opened project.json and modified it to add AngularJS.Core 1.3.4 as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",
    "AngularJS.Core": "1.3.4" // I only added this line
},
```

I see the package downloaded and added to my packages folder, but the nupkg file has a content folder (with the actual *.js files I want added), but those files aren't being added to my project. There are no error messages or warnings of any kind (at least none via the package manager log).

I have also tried running `kpm --verbose install ...` and `kpm --verbose restore` via the command line, and I don't see anything useful for solving this.

I know I can manage this manually, but am I missing something? Is this a bug, or am doing this wrong, or are my expectations incorrect? I'm new to this ASP.NET vNext stuff, and this is my first time jumping into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't. KPM currently doesn't do anything with packages that contain content/powershell scripts/transforms etc.